Need the mechanic hours to replace a starter on a 98 GMC Savana V8
Need mechanic hours to replace a starter on a 98 GMC Savana V8

Again, for whomever VTC on this question, they are on-topic for the site. They aren't looking for what it costs, just the book hours, which is not a shopping/cost question.
